# nonlinear least square

Tags: optimization, nonconvex-programming

The following objective function is non-convex. How can we solve min$ \left|| A^{\dagger}A-I \right||_F $? Will adding an auxiliary matrix be helpful or not? I am trying to solve it using ADMM Any other suggestions?  the main equation is $y=Hx$ where $H=A^†A$ H is a transformation matrix that needs to be close to the identity matrix. And this is a part of the optimization problem which has other variables and constraints.

Comment: So $A$ is an unknown decision matrix. Are $y$ and $x$ known? If there are other "variables and constraints", you should explain them, because they may significantly change which kind of optimization you need to perform.

Comment: Note that you're attempting to approach an [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix).

Comment: there is another constraint where $A=(w1 \otimes w2) $ and both w1,w2 are variables. the full problem is  $\left\| \textbf{A}^\dagger \textbf{A} -\textbf{I}\right\|_F $ such that $A=(w1 \otimes w2) $

Comment: You may try to use a nonlinear solver directly